# A representation system of $\Gamma_0(Nl) \subseteq \Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modular-forms

For an integer $n$, let
$$ \Gamma_0(n) = \left\{ \left( \begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \in \operatorname{SL}_2 (\mathbb{Z})\bigg | c \equiv 0 \mod n\right\}.$$

Let $N, l$ be different primes.
Then what is a representation system of $\Gamma_0(Nl) \subseteq \Gamma_0(N)$?

It seems that $\beta_i = \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ Ni & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$ for $i = 0, \dots l-1$,
and $\beta_\infty = \left( \begin{matrix}a & b \\ N & l \end{matrix} \right)$,
where $al -Nb = 1$,
represent it.

But I can't show.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "representation system" of your group?

Comment: @BenGrossmann A representation system of the set $\{ \Gamma_0(Nl) \gamma | \gamma \in \Gamma_0(N) \}.$

Comment: That doesn't help; I am asking for the definition of "representation system"

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for a [generating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes it is. Thank you.

Comment: @BenGrossmann The OP means coset representatives either of the quotient on the right $\Gamma_0(N)/\Gamma_0(lN)$ or on the left $\Gamma_0(lN)\setminus \Gamma_0(N)$

Comment: @reuns Yes. I thought that this is a common word.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B(l)$ be the image of $\Gamma_0(l)$ in $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/l\Bbb{Z})$. Take some $r_j,s_i$ such that $$SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/l\Bbb{Z})=\bigcup_j r_j B(l)=\bigcup_i B(l)s_i\qquad (disjoint\ union)$$

The reduction $\bmod l$ is an homomorphism
$$f:\Gamma_0(N)\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/l\Bbb{Z})$$ Since $N,l$ are coprime then it is surjective. The kernel is contained in $\Gamma_0(Nl)$, and the image of $\Gamma_0(Nl)$ is $B(l)$. This implies that

$$\Gamma_0(N)/\Gamma_0(Nl)\cong f(\Gamma_0(N))/f(\Gamma_0(Nl))=SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/l\Bbb{Z})/B(l)$$
and similarly for the quotient on the left.

Take some representatives $R_j,S_i\in \Gamma_0(N),f(R_j)=r_j,f(S_i)=s_i$. Then $$\Gamma_0(N)=\bigcup_j R_j \Gamma_0(Nl)= \bigcup_i \Gamma_0(Nl) S_i\qquad (disjoint\ union)$$
Finally, show that $\{r_j\}$ can be taken to be $ \pmatrix{1&0\\*&1}\cup \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$ equivalently $\pmatrix{1&0\\*&1}\cup \pmatrix{0&b\\N&0}$ where $-Nb\equiv 1\bmod l$.

What about the $s_i$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much!